# python3: how to install python3-dev locally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I would like to install my own package in my local dir (I do not have the root privilege). How to install python3-dev locally?
I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to build it yourself from source... You can easily find a guide for that if you google it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Brew package manager to install pyhon locally by:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install
ruby ./install
```

add the Brew to the PATH variable (better insert it into bashrc)

```
PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$HOME/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH"
```

To install e.g. python3 run:

```
brew install python3
```